# Problem when uploading a web made in django to aws

Tags: python, django, amazon-web-services

I am followint this tutorial:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create-deploy-python-django.html#python-django-configure-for-eb

When I do:

```
eb deploy
```

I obtain the following error:

```
[2021-07-08T12:48:37.858Z] ERROR [4740]  : Command execution failed: Activity failed. (ElasticBeanstalk::ActivityFatalError)
caused by: DEPRECATION: Python 2.6 is no longer supported by the Python core team, please upgrade your Python. A future version of pip will drop support for Python 2.6
  Collecting APScheduler==3.7.0 (from -r /opt/python/ondeck/app/requirements.txt (line 1))
  /opt/python/run/venv/lib/python2.6/site-packages/pip/_vendor/requests/packages/urllib3/util/ssl_.py:318: SNIMissingWarning: An HTTPS request has been made, but the SNI (Subject Name Indication) extension to TLS is not available on this platform. This may cause the server to present an incorrect TLS certificate, which can cause validation failures. You can upgrade to a newer version of Python to solve this. For more information, see https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/security.html#snimissingwarning.
```

However I have a python version 3.9.5

My configuration file is:

```
option_settings:
  aws:elasticbeanstalk:container:python:
    WSGIPath: ebdjango.wsgi:application


container_commands:
  01_postgresql:
    command: sudo yum -y install gcc python-setuptools python-devel postgresql-devel
  02_postgresql:
    command: sudo easy_install psycopg2
```

Thank you

Comment: could you put the complete code you are using?

Comment: ok, I am going to put it